# Background Color isn't changed

Tags: java, android

I have a **"MainActivity.java"** class, and an inner class **"SquashCourtView"** which extends `SurfaceView` and implements `Runnable`.
 I'm trying to change the background color, but with no succsess. Any help?

```
// all required things are imported
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Canvas canvas;
    SquashCourtView squashCourtView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        squashCourtView = new SquashCourtView(this);
        setContentView(squashCourtView);
}

    class SquashCourtView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
            Thread ourThread = null;
            SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
            Paint paint;

        public SquashCourtView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            ourHolder = getHolder();
            paint = new Paint();

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
                drawCourt();

        }


        public void drawCourt() {
            if (ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);//the background
       ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` only once

nothing extra just add this

```
squashCourtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

and  your onCreate will be as

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    squashCourtView = new SquashCourtView(this);
    setContentView(squashCourtView);
    squashCourtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```

Happy Coding